# Routing Error in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I am trying a sample routing in angular2 to navigate between two pages. I am not get any error on my console but i could not see any content visible on my browser.

my appcomponent.ts is as following

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ContactListComponent} from './contact/contactList.component'
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/router';
import {RouteConfig} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <header>
            <nav>
                <a [routerLink] = "['Contact']" ></a>
                <a [routerLink] = "['NewContact']"></a>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [ContactListComponent,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@RouteConfig([
    {path : "/contacts ", name:"Contact" , component:ContactListComponent },
    {path: "/newContact", name:"NewContact", component:ContactListComponent}
])

export class AppComponent {

}
```

i gave the `<base href = "/">` in my index.html

have imported all the required libraries in the appmodule also

can anyone help me out in this problem why i am not getting any content on my browser.

Comment: Looks like you are using a pre-release version of Angular v2?